# Cant get any internet on Ubuntu 12.10!!

Tags: wireless

So i went into ubuntu and did the lspci command in terminal. results were" broadcom BCM4318 802.11 b/g wireless network adapter. Now what do i do? it wont even search for the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must install propietary software broadcom to use your wireless adapter. Go to "additional drivers", push `Alt`+`F2` and enter jockey.

This command open a windows with your drivers which can be installed. Get sure that your broadcom driver is already installed. After install the driver you must restart your laptop to changes take effect.

Comment: I'll just add that "Additional Drivers" was moved to "Software Sources". it's in the last len.

In 12.04 it's in System Settings, but in 12/10 it's different.
---
גם אני מדבר עברית ^^